# when installing artifact *zip file doesn't appear in local repo

Tags: maven

I have project with some configuration files and after run maven install I got *.zip archive in target directory. However in my local repo I have only pom file. I auusme it's because of `<packaging>pom</packaging>` drfined in pom.xml. How can I get *.zip file in local repo anyway?

Here is the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycomp.name</groupId>
        <artifactId>saas-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../saas-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <!-- TEST -->
    <artifactId>htdocs</artifactId>
    <name>htdocs</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly</id>
                        <goals><goal>single</goal></goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: remove `<packaging>pom</packaging>` or change to `<packaging>jar</packaging>`

Comment: Please show your pom file.

Comment: if I'll change <packaging> to be jar, I'll get jar no?

Comment: It looks like [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/faq.html#required-classifiers) it is said that "`<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` (...) will prevent the assembly artifact from simply being attached to the project."